# Difference between Objects of class and objects-array

Tags: java, arrays

Its part of codes.In the first part of code i wrote objects of class.This is fine i havent problem.My problem is on the second part of code

```
 Paper[] pin = new Paper[N]; //N are given by keyboard .
    for (int i=0; i < N, i++) //until the lenght N 
    {
        pin[i] = new Paper();
    }
    pin[0].setpencil(3); // the number 3 i random chose it from my mind,i have done get and set methods
    pin[0].getpencil(3);
```

i want to do it not for class and this is the second part of code down.If i want to create objects not using class this is right way?

```
int[] pin = new int[N]; 
for (int i=0; i < N, i++)
{
    pin[i] = new int();
}
pin[0].setpencil(3);
pin[0].getpencil(3);
```

Comment: Question is obscure. *"i want to create objects not using class"*. You can only *create* objects of classes. `int` is a *primitive*, not a class, and you cannot "create" an `int`. `int[]` is an *array* of primitives, and all arrays are classes, and the array can be created. When you create an array of objects, all array elements are by default `null`, which is why you then need to create the objects too. When you create an array of primitives, all array values are by default `0` (or `false`). Nothing more to create.

Comment: Sorry i didnt mentioned good.You are right.I mean in the first case Paper is a class. I want to create an array and use objects but not to use the Paper class I want to use numbers(until N the lenght of the array) . I hope you understand me now

Comment: It will be only int thats why i use int. Do you understand me?

Comment: So you want to put numbers into an array of `Paper`? This isn't making any sense.

Comment: Sorry. Now i confused

Comment: We know that. Are you looking for an array of `Integer`? `new Integer[N]`? That will work, but so will `new int[N]`, and it's unclear why you would prefer the former.

Comment: `Integer` is a class.  `int` is a primitive.  Just pointing that out, since there seems to be some communication issues here.

Comment: In the first Paper is a class.I have declare Paper as a clsss .Public class Paper and i do many things on that class.On my main project i have written all this.I talk only for the first code.If Paper wansnt a Class .How could i do just the same thing to create objects on my main ?

Comment: I cannot understand most of that. Please try harder to express yourself clearly, including correct spelling and puncuation and grammar and capitalization. But you have already created an array of things that aren't classes in your second example.

Comment: Yes new int[] .On my second code .Of you could write it as answer.Guys sorry for my bad english its not my language english

Comment: "If Paper wasn't a class" that's not possible.  The only things that aren't classes are primitives like `int`; you can't make your own.  (And primitives have no methods.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use an array of integers, just use `int[N]`.

```
int[] pin = new int[N];
```

That's it.  Java initializes primitives for you to 0 (zero) or `false` for `boolean`.  You do not need a for loop to set the contents of the array, unless you want some value other than zero.

For example, to initialize all values of your array to 42:

```
int[] pin = new int[N]; 
for (int i=0; i < N, i++)
{
    pin[i] = 42;
}
```

To read and write this array, you cannot use methods.  Just treat the array deference like any other variable.

```
pin[0] = 3;                    // pin[0].setpencil(3);
System.out.println( pin[0] );  // pin[0].getpencil(3); prints "3"
```

However, classes must work differently (or at least they do in Java).  If you have an object array instead of primitives:

```
Class Paper {
   void getpencil(int n) {}
   void setpencil(int n) {}
}
```

and an array

```
Paper[] myPaper = new Paper[N];
```

You must access this through methods; you cannot use the form above which is only for primitives.

```
myPaper[0].setpencil(3);
myPaper[0].getpencil(3);
```

Comment: And everything i wrote down .I mean the whole objects as i refered will work fine?

Comment: I don't understand "whole objects" here.  The only object in my example is the array itself `pin`.  The deference (like `pin[2]`) are basically just variables.

Comment: Forget pin[i]=42. If you wrote pin[0].setpencil(7); // 7 random number .Will work or not? I want to use objects

Comment: For example you wrote // pin[0].setpencil(3); could i wrote this instead of pin[0]=3;

Comment: If you declare your array as `Paper[] pin` and `Paper` declares a method `setpencil(int n)` then yes that will work.  (You have two "pin" arrays, one for `Paper` and one for `int`.  It might have been better to name them differently so it would be clear which one was being discussed.)

Comment: I want to forget my first code with paper. The question on this comments for example.. can i wrote it with that way? Thanks :)

Comment: See my edit at the end.  Does that clear it up?  `pin` and `myPaper` are two different arrays now.

Comment: I got it for class Paper i can use method myPaper[0].getpencil(3); but for int the array pin because isnt a class i cant use the methods pin[0].setpencil(3); .Am i right?

Comment: Correct.  Primitives have no "methods" associated with them, and Java doesn't support the sort of access shorthand that allows class methods to be accessed like fields.  I'm pretty sure the ways I list above are the *only* ways in Java to access a class or primitive, ignoring reflection.